# HP ilo Bulk Certificate update

Tags: hp, certificate, ilo, bulk

I have a mixture of iLo 1-4 to update the self signed certs to use our CA. I have found some tools for the version 3/4 through PS and the new HP cmdlets. So two questions.

1. Anyone know a way to bulk update iLo1 and 2?
2. Using my script for version 3 and 4 it works until it getsto the point to install the cert and fails and the Test-path (line 111 I believe) because when it creates the file instead of creating a .cer it is creating a .rsp so it comes back false. i cannot for the life of me figure out why it is a .rsp any ideas? Script link below

https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-30615

Comment: sorry line 128 on this link - i removed some dead space on my local copy

Comment: I'm curious why you do this. I'm in and out of some large environments and never go through this effort for ILO devices.

Comment: Because in 2020 people are using Let's Encrypt rather than buying certificates.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest leveraging [python-hpilo](https://github.com/seveas/python-hpilo).

(for reals)

Comment: downloaded - will see if I can get it figured out in this. (havent used python much so new learning curve lol)

Comment: There's a command line tool. You don't need to know Python.